# autosubmit drop down value into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, onchange

i'm trying to auto submit the value of drop down menu using onchange=this.form.submit() into database but i couldn't make it work. can anyone please help me. any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

here is the code:

```
<? 
require_once ('database.php');
?>

<form action="" method=post>
<select name="assignee"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="0">Unassigned</option>   
        <?
        $find_selected = mysql_query("select assign_to from orders where id = $id");
        $asignee =mysql_fetch_row($find_selected);
        $list=mysql_query("SELECT id, full_name from user where username <> 'root' and nature = 3");
        while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
        ?>
        <option value="<? echo $row_list['id']; ?>"<? if($row_list['id']== $asignee['0']){ echo "selected"; } ?>><? echo $row_list['full_name'] ?></option>
        <?
        }
        mysql_free_result($list);
        mysql_free_result($find_selected);
        ?>
</select>
</form>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql = "UPDATE `orders` SET `assign_to` =  '{$_POST['assignee']}' WHERE `id` = '$id' ";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());    
}


?>
```

Comment: There's no element with a `name="submit"` in this code, perhaps you meant `isset($_POST['assignee'])` instead?

Comment: how you get $id ? And use PDO and MySQLi for database access this functions are deprecated.

Comment: escape your input! Unless you want to meet [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @shashikant $id is based on the order id

Comment: @Scuzzy i tried using isset($_POST['assignee']) but its not updated into database..

Comment: then I wonder if your method attribute missing the quotation marks is affecting it.

Comment: @PeterFischaleck could u explain more further? sorry i dont understand..

Comment: every string you get from a user is dangerous and could be used for a [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). escape your parameters for example with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/it/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['assignee'])){

$sql = "UPDATE `orders` SET `assign_to` =  '{$_POST['assignee']}' WHERE id=$id";    
mysql_query($sql);
}

?>
```

You just defined your query but didn't executed it

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake..but it still unable to update into database

Comment: try to var_dump($_POST['assignee']); to see if your form is submitted and what's submitted

Comment: when i choose a value in drop down menu..it output string(3) "212"  .."212" is actually the user_id

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE \`orders\` SET \`assign_to\` = '$_POST['assignee']' where \`ID\`= '$id' "

Comment: still syntax error :( unless i do like '{$_POST['assignee']}' but it still wont works

Comment: Does it work if you put manually a value instead of using the result of the post request like `$sql = "UPDATE \`orders\` SET \`assign_to\` = '5' where \`ID\`= '$id' "` ?